# React Native: How to render a list further down a scrollview?

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

Good day,

I'm building a React Native app with expo and I have a list of photos that I need to render but further down the screen.

My problem is that I need a scrollview to render the content before, but I can't have a list inside a scrollview so I tried to put my flatlist just after the closing tag scrollview but now the flatlist renders mid-page and the above content is scrollable from mid page up.

What i'm trying to do is have a continued view from the top of the screen to the end of my flatlist.
I've tried setting the flex of my scrollview at 1 so it would take up all the screen but it doesn't.

Thank you for your help!!!

EDIT

renderFeed = (data) =>

```
    <View style={{ marginTop: 25, marginLeft: 5 }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('EditContact', { id: data.item.id })}>
            <Image style={{ width: 300, height: 300, marginRight: 5 }}
                source={{ uri: data.item.profile }}>
            </Image>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={{ color: '#fff', fontSize: 20, marginBottom: 10, marginTop: 10, marginLeft: 5, alignSelf: 'center' }}>{data.item.name}</Text>
    </View>
```

render() {

```
    return (

        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View>
              // top of the page outside of scrollview
            </View>
            <ScrollView>
                <View>
                  // some text and a horizontal flatlist that renders as 
                  // expected
                </View>
                </ScrollView>
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.infoSource}
                renderItem={item => this.renderFeed(item)}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
                numColumns={2}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @JanakNirmal Thank you, I've added the code, please let me know if you need to know more, I'm not used to posting here yet just recently got into programming

Comment: Add your scrollview content in FlatList header component. It will solve your issue I believe.